# Refreshing ListBox items every few seconds C#

Tags: c#, listbox, visual-studio-2015

```
List<string> listbox = new List<string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (var proc in processes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.ProcessName))
            listbox.Add(proc.ProcessName);
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = listbox;
}
```

While using that code, I get a ListBox (listBox1) which shows all of the currently running processes, but what can I adjust of this code/add to make it refresh the ListBox every 5 seconds, since it only shows the programs that were open when the application was opened, and if an application is closed/opened while it is opened, it won't be added to the ListBox, hence why I want it to refresh every 5 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
private Timer m_Timer;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshProcesses();

    m_Timer = new Timer();

    m_Timer.Interval = 5000;
    m_Timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    m_Timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshProcesses();
}

private void RefreshProcesses()
{
    List<string> listbox = new List<string>();

    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (var proc in processes)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.ProcessName))
            listbox.Add(proc.ProcessName);
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = listbox;
}
```